# Couldnt reach to Tomcat through HTTP

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, networking, connection

I have installed `Tomcat 8.0.32` in Linux.
Started the server without problem. I can see the server logs no problem.

It runs in 8008 port.

```
29-Feb-2016 13:42:51.406 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8008"]

29-Feb-2016 13:42:51.418 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

29-Feb-2016 13:42:51.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1085 ms
```

But when I try http://ipaddress:8008/  I couldn't get the tomcat home page. But I do `netstat` I see its listening the port:

```
[root@localhost logs]# netstat -na | grep 8008

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Anyone get an idea, what could be the reason?

Comment: provide ip-number details

Comment: also tell us what exactly you get in response.... is it 500 error, 4xx error or blank page... without that there's no clue about issue

Comment: [root@localhost logs]# ifconfig
114.18.148.168

Comment: When I hit the URL, it keeps trying and throwing the below error:
The page cannot be displayed.. Please make sure the web address 
http://114.18.148.168:8008/ is correct..
In chrome it shows  Network Error (tcp_error) A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"

The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Comment: Look up in `netstat -anp` output, that which process has the port 8008.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that port 8008 is allowed through your firewall?  Based on your IP I can't tell exactly what service you're using but 8008 is not a standard port to allow through.  8080 is the standard Tomcat port and 80 is the normal HTTP port.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem...
The port was not open.

Issued the below commands to open the port and I am able to access it now.

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8008 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8008 --syn -j ACCEPT